# Body background on a responsive layout

Tags: css, background, breakpoints

[Please have a look at the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGKxC.png)

My Design is responsive which has blocks in the content. For the first two blocks i want to bg to be grey color. I have tried using gradients to the body but on certain breakpoints it does not work well.

Answer (score 0):

Use containers to group items together.

```
<body>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="grey-container">
  <div id="box1">box1, grey</div>
  <div id="box2">box2, grey</div>
</div>
<div class="box3">box3, not grey</div>
</body>
```